# Not shutting down.It stuck on boot logo. Always have to force shutdown manually

Tags: boot, shutdown, 20.04

stuck on ubuntu dell logo every time shutdown.I haven't tried anything yet.[image]

Comment: Can you try pressing escape while it is trying to shutdown and posting the screen?

Comment: posted the screen picture